# How to share authentication between multiple Symfony applications (same db, multiple Kernels)?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, token, session-cookies

I have a Symfony 3 project that is split in **3 apps** (multiple Kernels, same database, different subdomains) : Front / Admin / Partner.
(Mainly did it to be able to use several Sonata Admin configs.)

When a user fill the login form in Front app, he is **redirected to the corresponding app** (subdomain) depending on his role.

My question is : **how to make him authenticated after this redirection ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why it was not working : my `var` folder was split by app therefore my `sessions` folder was not shared between apps.

```
 var
   |-- admin
   |    |-- cache
   |    |-- logs
   |    |-- sessions
   |-- front
   | ...
```

The solution was to define the same `save_path` in my apps session configs.
I also had to define the `cookie_domain` to hostname (without subdomain) in order to get one PHPSESSID cookie shared by all subdomains  :

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/'
        cookie_domain: 'mywebsite.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it works i needed to add `handler_id: session.handler.native_file` in session section and to share session between sub domains i needed to prefix by a dot the domain in cookie_domain section:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/'
        cookie_domain: .mywebsite.com
```